# Emoticons of whatsapp and telegram

Tags: android, whatsapp, emoticons

I search smilies / emoticons for my Android App.
I found that there are some open source sets available like used by pidgin.

But I was wondering about the emoticons used in Whatsapp.
They are basically very nice. Thus I thought that they are licensed by whatsapp.
Now I have installed the messanger "telegram" and I was suprised. They are using the same emoticons than in whatsapp. How can this work out?
Are the emoticons publicly available?

Answer (score 3):

Both Whatsapp and Telegram (and a lot of other messenger apps, browsers and operating systems) use the [Emoji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) sets.

The different types of Emoji are a result of different fonts for emoticons; they have a different appearance depending on the "font" used but the base is always a unicode set of characters.

Both Whatsapp and Telegram use the Apple implementation apparently, as Ivo's link specifies. Also see [this github](https://github.com/github/gemoji) for more licensing info.

Comment: does this mean, that I can use them if I provide the license informaiton in my code?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think they are actual of Whatsapp put part of an actual Font.

I don't know if anyone can see it but for example on [this wikipage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_%28Unicode_block%29) I can see all emoticons like they are on whatsapp, and they are actual symbols in unicode and not images.
EDIT: I can only see them on my iMac (Apple)

[This website](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode) says they are actual licensed by Apple if I understand correctly (note 2)

Answer (score 2):

WhatsApp and Telegram both use a font that has been made by Apple. Apple doesn't license this font, so what they are doing is actually illegal, although Apple apparently doesn't care.